# Ros subscriber not up to date

Tags: python, image, opencv, ros, subscriber

I have written a ROS subscriber to one of the image topics and I have set my buffer to 1 using:

```
subscriber =rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed",CompressedImage, callback,  queue_size=1)
```

However my subscriber still lags behind. Any idea what might be causing this? Am I setting the queue size correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The queue is for queueing incoming messages. This means, if your callback takes longer to proccess than new messages arrive, only `queue size` is kept, the others are not processed by your node.

I would suggest to print out a message in the publisher node before publishing and a message at the top of your callback method. Then you can exactly measure the time it takes for ros to handle your messages. All other timing issues will be possibly caused by your callback method.

Comment: I agree but if these other messages are not processed does that not mean that my subscriber will deal with the most recent one. As ausch, the video display should be choppy (due to skipped frames) but not lag behind?

Comment: Well, it should lag as long as it takes for your callback method to process.

Comment: I get it!! Because i will always show each message a few seconds after I receive it. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I was having the exact same problem (it wasnt the choppy framerate that was the issue, it was the actual lag). When I would kill whatever image source was publishing (rosbag, camera driver, etc.), my node would still process ~5-10 frames **even after the source was killed** (and I was sure I had `queue_size=1`)

Here is [the github issue](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/536) I made and it was resolved. It turns out there are multiple queues involved (not just the one that you set queue_size to 1). In my case, the default `buff_size` was smaller than my images, and so my node wasn't processing them fast enough, and there always was a number of images backed up in some queue.

TL;DR
increase the `buff_size` for your subscriber, as [I did here](https://github.com/chicagoedt/Software_IGVC/commit/34fc91a8662ef2f833af6865df0894d2b122917b). It worked for me :)

Comment: So basically the subscriber can drop only message that are already in its buffer completely. If the buffer is smaller than `queue_size + 1`, than no message is ever dropped and the TCP buffer is buffering your messages.

Answer (score 1):

A [supplement](https://answers.ros.org/question/220502/image-subscriber-lag-despite-queue-1/) to why buff_size matters.
Also [the official document](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) can help explain another reason that causes lag from the perspective of pub.publish.

> publish() in rospy is synchronous by default (for backward
>   compatibility reasons) which means that the invocation is blocking
>   until:
>
> the messages has been serialized into a buffer and that buffer has
>   been written to the transport of every current subscriber

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the *visible* lag is most probably that your callback function takes up a lot of time. If at all possible, try to fix that. Setting the queue size to 1 essentially means asking ROS to process whatever frames it can hold on to.

Set your queue size to a larger number, say 5 or 10. This way, (hopefully, if the processing delay isn't too much) all of your frames will be processed, but they'll be lagging behind in time. That is, the video processing will run a few steps behind but without any "jerks" and missing frames in between.

Comment: I don't mind a choppy picture. In fact I prefer that to a laggy one. The reason I use a queue size of one is so that I have the most up to date info when the callback is called. I dont need to process all of them, I just need to process the current one. And yes, my callback takes longer than the rate of incoming messages (Hard to change that).

Comment: In that case, what is the issue? A queue size of 1 will ensure just that.